# How can we form a mongoDB schema object in JavaScript for the JSON where keys are changing dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mongodb

I want to create a schema in mongoDB for using in an AngularJS project. But the keys for the json are changing dynamically. The json is like this:

```
{

    “1” : {

         “Name” : “John”,

         “City” : “London”

     },

    “2” : {

         “Name” : “Paul”,

         "City” : “New York”

      }

}
```

Here the keys are changing. They will always be in integer format for sure. For the values, I can have my schema like this: (using Javascript)

```
var dbObject = new Schema({
    Name: String,
    City: String
});
```

I am not sure how to include the key which will always be an Integer in this schema. Any pointers for creation of such a schema object in mongoDB?

Comment: you want to add data to DB or schema update?

Comment: I want to create a schema first. And then insert data. And later update it when there is an update query. So basically, all `CRUD` operations.

Comment: schema looks fine.

Comment: But what about the keys? We generally pass `"keys" : String` like this pattern. I am not sure if we need to include the regex for the keys?

Comment: If schema is fine, maybe I am confusing with the insert statement. Can you suggest an insert statement for a record with key "3", name=Chris, City = New York?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

```
var data = {
    "1": {
        "Name": "John",
        "City": "London"
    },
    "2": {
        "Name": "John",
        "City": "London"
    }
};


for (let key in data) {
    var val = data[key]; // get inner objects
    // call api
}
```

Comment: This will be helpful in retrieving any value for a given key. But what about inserting a new record with what I mentioned in comments earlier?

Comment: val will change dynamically based on the key inside the loop, you have to call API for insert data.

Comment: Will it be something like this:
var newKey = 3;
data[newKey] = new dbObject({name:Chris, City:New York});

Comment: Just bounced my server. Lets see. Will let you know. Thanks btw!

Comment: It works. I mentioned the command I used for inserting. Added that and accepted the answer.